# Problem adding OpenLayers satellite imagery to QGIS using OpenLayers plugin

Tags: qgis, openlayers

I receive the following error log when I try.  I am running QGIS s'Hertogenbosch 3.30.3.

```
2024-01-10T14:35:26     WARNING    NotImplementedError: QgsPluginLayer.setTransformContext() is abstract and must be overridden
             
2024-01-10T14:35:38     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users/kearn/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 140, in checkMapReady
              if self.page.mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("map != undefined"):
             RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type OLWebPage has been deleted
             
2024-01-10T14:38:33     WARNING    NotImplementedError: QgsPluginLayer.setTransformContext() is abstract and must be overridden
```

Comment: I should say this occurred after I upgraded the openlayers plugin most recently

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please do not comment on your own Question to introduce new information. Instead, [Edit] the Question.